# border-radius issue when using ::after

Tags: css

I have a yellow button with rounded corners, some text inside and a download image to the right of the text.

My button that is set up like so:

```
<a class="yellow-button" href="#">Some text</a>
```

I have styles set up like this:

```
.yellow-button {
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 13px 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0.875rem;

  &:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: url(../img/download-icon.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 16px 17px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    height: 18px;
    width: 16px;
  }
}
```

I'm having an issue where both corners of the right side of the button are not rounded but the left side corners are.

Comment: Your after block likely sticks out. Ty putting your border-radius on your 'after' block

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This was one of the first things that I tried but unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: overflow:hidden ?

Comment: Overflow: hidden did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem here is that you're putting an `inline-block` element within your link (`display: inline` by default). This is not always incorrect, but it definitely makes seeing what is going on with your layout trickier (i.e. your `<a>` by default won't behave as you want: the margin will never be applied).

Give your button `display: inline-block` and the problem goes away:

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 13px 30px;
}

.button:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: blue;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 18px;
  width: 16px;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" href="#">Some text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

add to `::after`  transparency on background, and same rounded corners

```
background-color:transparent;
border-radius: 0.375rem;
```

with a little more code and with the images, we could see exactly what the problem is

```css
.yellow-button {
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
  color: yellow;
  padding: 13px 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
 .yellow-button:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /* --------------- */
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 0.375rem;
    /* --------------- */
    background: url(../img/download-icon.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 16px 17px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    height: 18px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

```html
<a class="yellow-button" href="#">Some text</a>
```

Comment: Turns out some pre-existing css was throwing this off. There were floats and all kinds of other sizing and positioning properties that messed it up. Simply setting display: inline-block; saved the day.

Comment: I'm like that the solutions. There are certain CSS frameworks that can create conflicts with your elements. I highly recommend using Firefox Developer Edition, and inspecting using the tool for the 'Calculated' styles to look for properties different from the default ones.